# C++ error: cannot convert 'students' to 'students*'... - struct array in function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, reference

When I run the code below, I find that it generates an error that I'm unsure how to fix. Could someone help me please?

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int n=5;

struct students
{
    string firstname;
    float rate;
};

students A[n];
students B[n];

void writeStudents(students *TAB){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << "First name: ";
        cin >> TAB[i].firstname;
        cout << "Rate: ";
        cin >> TAB[i].rate;
    }
}

void printStudents(students *TAB, int rows, float difference){
    float average=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        average = average + TAB[i].rate;
    }
    average = average/n;
    for(int i=n-rows; i<n; i++){
        if(TAB[i].rate > average+difference){
           cout << TAB[i].firstname << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    writeStudents(A[n]);
    writeStudents(B[n]);
    printStudents(A[n], 2, 0.9);
    printStudents(B[n], 3, 1.2);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Console Log

```
error: cannot convert 'students' to 'students*' for argument '1' to 'void writeStudents(students*)' (line 54)
error: cannot convert 'students' to 'students*' for argument '1' to 'void writeStudents(students*)' (line 55)
error: cannot convert 'students' to 'students*' for argument '1' to 'void printStudents(students*)' (line 56)
error: cannot convert 'students' to 'students*' for argument '1' to 'void printStudents(students*)' (line 57)
```

Comment: Which part of the error message are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know why students cannot be converted.

Comment: Nothing specific to students. Try converting an `int` into an `int*` and you'll get the same problem.

Comment: The error is clear as itself

Comment: Use `writeStudents(A);` instead of `writeStudents(A[n]);`

Comment: Okay, now I understand, thank you guys!

Answer (score 4):

When used in an expression, `A[n]` means "the element of the array `A` at index `n`". This is wrong for two reasons: First you get a *single element* in the array, and pass it to a function that expects the array. The second problem is that index `n` is out of bounds.

Use just plain `A` and `B` when calling the functions, like e.g.

```
writeStudents(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (as a first step)?:

```
writeStudents(A);
writeStudents(B);
printStudents(A, 2, 0.9);
printStudents(B, 3, 1.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
writeStudents(A[n]);
writeStudents(B[n]);
printStudents(A[n], 2, 0.9);
printStudents(B[n], 3, 1.2);
```

Try this instead:

```
writeStudents(A);
writeStudents(B);
printStudents(A, 2, 0.9);
printStudents(B, 3, 1.2);
```